# Android - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, jar

I'm having a problem in my Android app and didn't find any related topic in the forum (maybe I just didn't know how to look for it)

I have a project that generates a .jar file with some classes I use in two other projects (basically a server-client structure, the Android app being the client). I have built another project in order to test specifically this generated .jar, and it works fine. When I add it to the android app I can declare and use the classes having no compilation problem, but when I execute the app (using BlueStacks) I get this ClassNotFoundException. If I keep clicking "Resume" I get also a NoClassDefFound exception when trying to instantiate one of the classes from the generated .jar.

Is there any extra configuration (other than including it in the build path) I have to make to be able to use or generate this .jar? I'm using Eclipse Kepler, Android 4.2.2 and Java 1.7.

Comment: Where is the jar located?

Newest versions of ADT require jars to be in the libs folder, where the android build system magically finds them.

Comment: @eli, they were not in the libs folder. Just moved it there but still getting the error!

Comment: In the build path, under the order and export tab, do you have Android Private Libraries checked?

Comment: I assume the same is true for the .jars you are bringing in? With src and gen checked when you exported the jar?

Comment: @eli the .jars weren't checked. Just checked them and it is still giving the same error. When I exported the .jar I did check the source and resouces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out what was wrong. My Android project compliance level is set to 1.6 and the project that generated the .jar was set to 1.7. I particularly found it very strange that nothing indicated this error... Either way, thanks to everyone who tried to help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to right click on your *jar* and select

> Build Path -> Add to Build Path

Sometimes the builder just doesn't pick up on libraries, even when they are set in, for example, the *libs* directory.

Comment: Are the projects in the same workspace? If yes, you can add the dependency by going to *Project->Preferences...*, selecting *Android*, and adding library at the bottom of the screen by pressing *Add*.

Comment: @Phil - It sounds from the questions as though he's using .jar files, not android libraries. They are two different things.

Comment: @Phil They are in the same workspace. I tried to do this and when I click in add, it doesn't show the other project, do I need to make any additional configuration to that project?

Comment: @GustavoSgarbiCampos, on your library project, you need to click *Project->Preferences...*, select *Android*, and check the box *is Library*. Now it will show up in the list for your other project.

Comment: @Phil, the thing is, the project that generates the jar is not an Android project, it just contains some classes that I will use in the Android project!